# Android. Compose, accompanist pager, how to start pager from specific position with infinite pager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-jetpack-compose, infinite-scroll, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I'm using `com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager` to implement infinite scroll of pages. I implemented everything as described in HorizontalPagerLoopingSample.
I need show my pager starting from third page. But when I set initialPage = 2 HorizontalPager showing wrong page.
In the sample to show the first page is set `initalPage = Int.MAX_VALUE / 2`. Is it possible to calculate real specific position with infinite pager ?

I try to do something like this:

```
val positionFromIWantToStart = 2
 val startIndex = (Int.MAX_VALUE / 2) + positionFromIWantToStart
 val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = startIndex)
```

But this is not working correct, `HorizontalPager` always show first page.

Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is more a math question :)

I think it should be something like this:

```kotlin
val yourList = (1..5).map { it.toString() }
val colors = listOf(Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue, Color.Yellow, Color.Magenta)

val positionFromIWantToStart = 3
val itemsCount = yourList.size

val numPages = Int.MAX_VALUE / itemsCount
val startPage = numPages / 2
val startIndex = (startPage * itemsCount) + positionFromIWantToStart

val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = startIndex)

HorizontalPager(
    state = pagerState,
    count = Int.MAX_VALUE
) { index ->
    val page = index % itemsCount
    Text(
        text = "Page ${yourList[page]}",
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(colors[page]),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but unfortunately in this case the pager always starts with zero index (first page)

Comment: I updated my answer with the full code and it works fine. Please, take a look.